# Changing the style of button after entering the inputs in edit text (Android)

Tags: android

I want to change the style of my Log In button in my Log In activity after say the user fills up the username and password fields..Just to show the user that the button is enabled now..

```
mLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String Username,Password;
        Username = mUserName.getText().toString();
        Password = mPassword.getText().toString();
        if(Username.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"enter username",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(Password.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"enter password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(Username.length() != 0 && Password.length() != 0) {
            mLogIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
            mLogIn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bg);
        }
    }
});
```

I tried this .. But it changes after i click .. Any other suggestions please..

Comment: You show no screenshots and no code, how should we help you?

Comment: Code added .. have a look ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sth like this:

```
    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {
      /* Change Button state here */
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you building a native or hybrid app? If it is the latter try this code:

In your JS, do this:

```
    function Enabled(){
var us = $('#user').val();
var pa = $('#pass').val();
if(us!=='' && pa!==''){
    $('#buttonid').prop('disabled',false);
    }
}
```

In your html do this:

```
<input type="text" id="user" onclick="Enabled();">
<input type="password" id="pass" onclick="Enabled();">
    <button disabled id="buttonid" >Click Me</button>
```

Note: Make sure you have jQuery in your `<head>` tag. E.g.

```
<script src="jQuery-2.0.0" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to disable the login button initially e.g. via xml `android:enabled="false"` or via code. Then add a `TextWatcher` to the username and password and enable the login button when the fields are non empty:

```
public class Example extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher {
    EditText mUserName;
    EditText mPassword;
    Button mLogIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // ...
        mUserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        mLogIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
        mUserName.addTextChangedListener(this);
        mPassword.addTextChangedListener(this);
        mLogIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mLogIn.setEnabled(false); // TODO the saved state may break here things.
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO the login
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        mLogIn.setEnabled(mUserName.getText().length() > 0 && mPassword.getText().length() > 0);  
    }
    // not used:
    @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
}
```